# Regex url redirect in apache

Tags: regex, redirect

i want to redirect pages in apache, so i tried this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?page_id=671 http://letempspourtoit.fr/news [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

but it just redirect to the home page. So i tried to escape the question mark like this :

```
RewriteRule ^/\?page_id=671 http://letempspourtoit.fr/news [L,R=301]
```

no success...

Any hint greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) works on URL-paths, and query strings are not considered part of the path. You need a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) on `QUERY_STRING`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=671$
RewriteRule ^/$ http://letempspourtoit.fr/news [L,R=301]
```

As you can see, the path for the `RewriteRule` is `/`.

Your `RewriteRule` worked for URLs like `http://host/%3Fpage_id=671`, that is: URLs with a `%`-encoded question mark.